# How to configure links with HasNavigationPropertiesLink after latest WebAPI beta (26-Jun-2013) Update

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have a basic POCO (No database) structure implementing an OData Service with the latest WebAPI update.  Unfortunately, the latest update broke the HasNavigationPropertiesLink code that I had to generate links which can be used for $expand operations.  Here is my old code:

```
var jobs = modelBuilder.EntitySet<Job>("Jobs");
jobs.EntityType.NavigationProperties,
            (entityContext, navigationProperty) => new 
             Uri(entityContext.UrlHelper.Link(ODataRouteNames.PropertyNavigation, 
                   new 
                      { 
                           Controller = "Jobs", 
                           parentId = entityContext.EntityInstance.ID,
                           NavigationProperty = navigationProperty.Name 
                       })));
```

And here is my new code (that doesn't work):

```
var jobs = modelBuilder.EntitySet<Job>("Jobs");
jobs.EntityType.NavigationProperties,
            (entityContext, navigationProperty) => new 
             Uri(entityContext.Url.Link(<??WHAT GOES HERE??>, 
                   new 
                      { 
                           Controller = "Jobs", 
                           parentId = entityContext.EdmObject,
                           NavigationProperty = navigationProperty.Name 
                       })),
                       true);
```

Any help is much appreciated - this doesn't seem to have been documented in the updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like the version of the OData bits you are using is very old. In our current version, you can use the ODataConventionsModelBuilder to create a model that defines navigation properties and links following conventions, so unless you need to generate custom links, it's a better way to go. However, if you want to generate a custom navigation link, the link generation code looks something similar to this:

```
        var jobs = builder.EntitySet<Job>("Jobs");
        jobs.HasNavigationPropertiesLink(customers.EntityType.NavigationProperties,
            (context, navigationProperty) =>
            {
                var result = "http://mydomain.com/prefix/odataPath";
                //In order to generate this link you can use context.Url.ODataLink(new EntityPathSegment("Jobs"), ...);
                return new Uri(result);
            }, followsConventions: true);
```

Answer (score 0):

it is better to use `ODataConventionsModelBuilder` as Javier has suggested. But if you still want to set up your own odata model you can do it:

```
var jobs = builder.EntitySet<Job>("Jobs");
        jobs.HasNavigationPropertiesLink(customers.EntityType.NavigationProperties,
            (context, navigationProperty) => context.GenerateNavigationPropertyLink(navigationProperty, false)
            , followsConventions: true);
```